# Android Context Unavailable In Listener Class Preventing New Intent Creation

Tags: java, android, android-intent, event-listener

I am new to android development and while working with intents, I have a payment intent and a payment listener and I am trying to fire another activity or intent when the listener picks up a payment response. The issue is, I am unable to get context int listener class implementation.

The class that I am trying to create a new intent in is:

```
public class PaymentConnectorListener implements IPaymentConnectorListener {
    @Override
    public void onSaleResponse(SaleResponse response) {
        String result;
        if (response.getSuccess()) {
            result = "Sale was successful";
        } else {
            result = "Sale was unsuccessful" + response.getReason() + ":" + response.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

}

How I initialize the listener class is:

```
    final IPaymentConnectorListener ccListener = new PaymentConnectorListener();
```

and where I use the listener is:

```
paymentConnector =  new PaymentConnector(this, account, ccListener, remoteApplicationId);
            paymentConnector.initializeConnection();
```

I want to fire an intent on payment response but the onSaleResponse() method does not have context. Also, switching from angular, can you explain a bit more of what context is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify your code to include the Context parameter in the constructor

```
public class PaymentConnectorListener implements IPaymentConnectorListener {
    private Context context;

    public PaymentConnectorListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaleResponse(SaleResponse response) {
        String result;
        if (response.getSuccess()) {
            result = "Sale was successful";
        } else {
            result = "Sale was unsuccessful" + response.getReason() + ":" + response.getMessage();
        }

        // Use the context to start a new activity or create a new intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("result", result);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

When initializing the PaymentConnectorListener, pass the appropriate Context object to its constructor

```
final IPaymentConnectorListener ccListener = new PaymentConnectorListener(this);
```

Make sure that this refers to a valid Context object within the scope where you are initializing the PaymentConnectorListener

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly fine, but for some reason the onSaleResponse(SaleResponse response) method is not sometimes.